# Assigning std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, std, shared-ptr

In my code, I had ordinary pointer that was dynamically allocated

```
class Texture
{
    //code...
    SDL_Texture* m_texture;
};
```

I had Init() function from Texture class allocated SDL_Texture*, and destructor released memory.

However, this turned out to be a problem. I had to use shared_ptr, because I was using same texture for different objects, which would be destroyed, and thus disallowing me to display them properly(after first object from vector is destroyed, the texture(which is shared for all objects of same type) is gone).

So I decided to use shared_ptr, but I have one problem with it - I don't know how to assign something to shared_ptr's :

```
//Old code:
m_texture = loadTexture();

//New code:

class Texture
{
   std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture> m_texture;
};
//code...

m_texture = loadTexture(); // Error! No assignment operator
```

I tried .get() function, but it's rvalue, so I can't assign anything to it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [.reset()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) method

Comment: What does `loadTexture()` return?

Comment: Actually I made a small mistake in writing code above(in post), but it won't matter.

Code looks like m_texture.reset( SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface ) );

SDL_CreateTextureFromSurfacce returns SDL_Texture*  


PS. Since I tried using .reset(), I did it like this:

m_texture.reset( SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface ) );

And sweet template-errors, and I have absolutely no idea what does it mean. And sorry for terrible comment, but I can't figure out how to format it(yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom deleter, too:

```
#include <memory>

// Fake SDL library

typedef void SDL_Texture;

SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(/*SDL_Renderer* , SDL_Surface* */) {
    return 0;
}

void SDL_DestroyTexture(SDL_Texture* texture)
{}

// Shared

typedef std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture> SharedTexture;

inline SharedTexture make_shared(SDL_Texture* texture) {
    return SharedTexture(texture, SDL_DestroyTexture);
}

int main() {
    SharedTexture texture;
    texture = make_shared(SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface());
}
```

Please be aware, a C library:

- may use an opaque type
- has it's own function for deletion or is using free

Answer (score 4):

`std::shared_ptr` does not let you assign a plain pointer to it directly. When you think about, there are quite convincing reasons to disallow it implicitly happening. First of all, `shared_ptr` needs an (external, in general) reference counter to be allocated. Consider for example the following (hypothetical) code:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = obj;
std::shared_ptr<A> p2 = obj;
```

What happens when the pointers fall out of scope? Each assignment creates its own reference counter, since there is no way `p2` can know about the one created by `p1`. In effect, `obj` is deleted twice - UB.

Preferred solution is to use library function `std::make_shared`. It offers a number of benefits over wrapping externally created object:

- counter is created in the same heap chunk as the object, hence the overhead of memory allocation is reduced, and the memory coherency is increased
- it offers greater exception safety - look [here](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/) for a good reference on problems it avoids

Another option is to derive the classes you manage by `shared_ptr` from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Such objects maintain necessary structures as data members, and so the first benefit of `make_shared` is retained. In addition, initializing `shared_ptr`'s in the way described in the first example becomes valid, since the constructors/copy-assignment operators can recognize `std::enable_shared_from_this` subclasses and use the internal structures for bookkeeping, hence both `p1` and `p2` will use the same reference counter, stored inside `obj`.

Sometimes, though, as in this case, it is not possible to use any of the strategies described above. If you really need to set a `shared_ptr` directly, there is a method to do it - `reset()`. Use it with caution, though, and make sure to wrap a pointer in a `shared_ptr` as soon as possible, and let it manage it since then. Especially I consider good practice to encapsulate creation of such resource in a method and never expose the wrapped pointer outside it.

Comment: ''m_texture = std::make_shared<SDL_Texture>( SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface ) );''

I decided to try ''std::make_shared''. I did it like I posted, but this won't work for me.
It displays STL errors, again. It says that it can't use operator sizeof on incomplete SDL_Texture type(if I understood this error correctly)